# 'laravel-echo-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-echo, socket.io-redis

```
laravel-echo-server init
```

When i want to run this command in my project directory.

Project directory is `D:\xampp\htdocs\app>`
when i run this, it show that

> laravel-echo-server is not recognized as internal or external command
>   operable program or batch file.

Any help?

Comment: I believe there is no such executable as `laravel-echo-server`. I guess you need to run `php` command passing necessary arguments to it (probably `laravel-echo-server` is name of the php script and so that it should follow after `php` command)

Comment: i tried it. but when i run php laravel-echo-server init 
it shows following error "Could not open input file: laravel-echo-server"

Comment: well, I am not sure about all of that, probably you try to follow some manual? Probably you forgot to add extension to the file? I mean `php laravel-echo-server.php init`? You should try to find file called `laravel-echo-server` and pass it as argument using absolute path.

Comment: 'laravel-echo-server init' this is the command . may i change the path in environmental variables. i am stuck with this issue.

Comment: laravel-echo-server is a Node package as you can see here https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server. @AbdulWahabInvincible Did you installed the laravel-echo-server inside your Laravel project?

Comment: yeah, just googled it. Firstly you need to run `npm install -g laravel-echo-server` (https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)

Comment: Initialize with CLI Tool
Run the init command in your project directory:

$   `laravel-echo-server init`

this is the process . writer write this. thats why i am asking . 
after this command 
laravel-echo-server.json file will setup in project directory.

Comment: yes sir i first run `npm install -g laravel-echo-server` this command .
after this i move to init command.

Comment: It Still not working . laravel-echo-server is not recognized as an external or internal command.

Comment: try install without `-g` flag, probably that can help. It should work. Try open cmd again. This seems to be an issue about node / npm installation.

Comment: i tried but not still working .. i tried it with out `-g`

Answer (score 3):

After the install it seems the installation directory is

```
C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Just copy it in yours project folder and run again:

```
laravel-echo-server init
```